# Localization of lattices over Dedekind domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

I'm trying to understand the proof of lemma 4.12 on modules over Dedekind domains from Frohlich and Taylor's book 'Algebraic Number Theory' page 94.

I have a Dedekind domain $\mathcal o$, a non-zero prime ideal $\mathfrak p$, its field of fractions $K$ and a finite dimensional $K$-vector space $V$.

The Lemma states

> Let $L$ and $M$ be $\mathcal o$-lattices in $V$. Then for almost all $\mathfrak p$ $L_\mathfrak p=M_\mathfrak p$.
>
> $Proof$.  Choose free $\mathfrak o$-lattices $F'$ and $F''$ in $V$ with $F''\subset L,M\subset F'$. Let $l$ be an automorphism of the $K$-vector space $V$, mapping a basis of $F'$ onto one of $F''$. For almost all $\mathfrak p$ the matrix representing $l$ has $\mathfrak p$-integral entries and a $\mathfrak p$-unit determinant. For all such $\mathfrak p$, $F_\mathfrak p'=F_\mathfrak p''$, hence $M_\mathfrak p\subset L_\mathfrak p$. Similarly for almost all $\mathfrak p$, $L_\mathfrak p\subset M_\mathfrak p$. This gives the result.

1) I know that I can choose free $\mathfrak o$-lattices $F'$ and $F''$ such that $F'\subset L\subset F''$ and similarly for $M.$ But how can we choose two such lattices which bound both $L$ and $M$?

2) How come the matrix representing $l$ have entries in the localization $\mathcal o_\mathfrak p$? I thought $l$ was $\mathfrak o$-linear. Does the book mean the tensored mapping $1\otimes l$ on $V_\mathfrak p=\mathcal o_\mathfrak p \otimes_\mathcal o V$?

3) Why is the above true for almost all $\mathfrak p$?

I'll be very grateful for answers to any of the questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Since both are lattices in the same $K$-vector space $V$ one can find nonzero elements $a,b\in \mathcal O$ such that $aM\subseteq L\subseteq b^{-1}M$: take a basis $(e_i)_{i=1,\dots,n}$ of $V$ contained in $M$; since $KL=V$ there is $x\in K$, $x\ne 0$ such that $xe_i\in L$ for all $i$, so $xM\subseteq L$. Now write $x=a/a'$ with $a,a'\in\mathcal O$ and conclude that $aM\subseteq L$. (For the other containment change $M$ by $L$.) Now should be easy to find two free modules $F'$ and $F''$ of the same rank with $F''\subset L,M\subset F'$.
2) $l$ is a matrix whose entries are in $K$. If localize $\mathcal O$ at a prime ideal $\mathfrak p$, then some denominators of the entries of $l$ are in $\mathfrak p$ and some others don't. But there are only finitely many denominators, so for almost all primes $\mathfrak p$ these are outside of $\mathfrak p$. The same holds for the determinant of $l$. Furthermore, we also have that the determinant has the numerator outside of $\mathfrak p$ for almost all $\mathfrak p$. Thus $l$ is an invertible matrix with entries in $\mathcal O_{\mathfrak p}$ for almost all $\mathfrak p$. It follows that the basis of $F'_{\mathfrak p}$ belongs to $F''_{\mathfrak p}$ for almost all primes $\mathfrak p$, that is, $F'_{\mathfrak p}=F''_{\mathfrak p}$ for almost all primes $\mathfrak p$.

Comment: So to clarify, since an $\mathcal O$-basis of $F'$ is also a $K$-basis of $V$, are we considering an arbitrary $K$-automorphism $l$ of $V$ and then looking at the matrix of $l(v'_i)$ wrt $v''_i$ where $\{v'_i\}$ and $\{v''_i\}$ are given given $\mathcal O$-bases of $F'$ and $F''$ respectively? Also could you explain why the basis of $F'_\mathfrak p$ belongs to $F''_\mathfrak p$ for almost all primes $\mathfrak p$? Regards

Comment: To the first question the answer is yes. For the second: take into account that $\mathcal O$ is a Dedekind domain, so any non-zero element is contained in only finitely many primes.

Comment: @user26857 A stupid question but further to Mark Rodriguez's comment, are we in fact choosing a second $\mathcal O$-basis $\{v'''_i\}$ of $F''$ beforehand and defining $l$ to be the automorphism of $V$ which maps $v'_i$ to $v'''_i$ for each $i$? Otherwise I can't see how $l$ can even be defined so as to give rise to a non-identity matrix.

Comment: @user26857 This is my attempt for the last part. $1\otimes_\mathcal{O}l$ is a $\mathcal{O}_\mathfrak p$-isomorphism from $F'_\mathfrak p$ into $F''_\mathfrak p$ and if $l(v'_i)=\sum_j l_{ij}v''_j$ then $(1\otimes_\mathcal{O} l)(1\otimes_\mathcal O v'_i)=1\otimes_\mathcal O l(v'_i)=1\otimes \sum_j l_{ij}v''_j=1\otimes_K\sum_jl_{ij}v''_j=\sum_j(l_{ij}\otimes_Kv''_j)=\sum_j(l_{ij}\otimes_\mathcal O v''_j)\in \mathcal O_\mathfrak p\otimes_\mathcal O F''$ for almost all $\mathfrak p$ since the denominators of each $l_{ij}$ lies in only finitely many primes. Is this what you had in mind? Regards

Comment: @user26857 I would be very grateful if you could tell me your argument showing why the basis of $F'_\mathfrak p$ belongs to $F''_\mathfrak p$. best regards